# presenting ViewController Label from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm new in programming IOS Apps with swift.
I've programed TabBar in AppDelegate.swift with the code, and with 2 ViewControllers program in MainPageViewController.swift and DetailViewController.swift.

```
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let mainPageVC = MainPageViewController()
    let detailVC = DetailViewController()
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [mainPageVC,detailVC]
    let mainTabBar = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "03")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "06")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal))
    let detailTabBar = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "02")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "05")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal))
    mainPageVC.tabBarItem = mainTabBar
    deviceVC.tabBarItem = deviceTabBar
    mainPageVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    deviceVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 1, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1)
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And then I added a  Label in the MainPageViewController.swift

```
class MainPageViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainTabBarItem: UITabBarItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backgraondLayer = color.gl
    backgraondLayer.frame = view.frame
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(backgraondLayer, atIndex: 0)
    testLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

I keep getting the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. 
And if I remove the "Label.backgroundColor" code and setup the background color in the Attribute Inspector, the Build App will not shown the Label.

What code did i miss?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it gives you "nil while unwrapping an optional value" in `testLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()`, the chances are that your label is not connected to the control in Interface Builder. In the editor the IBOutlets have little circle next to the declaration. Empty one for unconnected and circle with dot inside for connected.

If you are still at the beginning of your app dev, consider doing the UITabBarController plumbing in Interface Builder/Storyboard. It will save you from some boring work every time you add a new tab.

Comment: The main reason why i choose not to do UITabBarController in Builder/Storyboard is because i need the TabBarItems images in Original Image. If I build it in the Builder, i don't know how to revise it to original image. And yes, I've check the connection problem before, seems not to be the reason. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it resolves the problem, but if you go to Assets and select the icon, you can set "Render As" to Default, Original or Template.

Comment: Yes, setting "Render As" to Original Image worked as i expected. Thanks for the help!